# angular-chart.js not rendering any chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using the dependency angular-chart.js in my angular-project to display some data visualizations on my admin page.

Last week, I upgraded my angular-chart.js to the 1.1 version and Chart.hs to the 2.5 version, according to the README.md on their git page. But since I have upgraded, my charts no longer appear...

There is my code HTML :

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
    chart-data="vm.data" chart-labels="vm.labels" chart-series="vm.series"></canvas>
```

And my JS code :

```
 export default function BarChartController(){
     var vm = this;

     vm.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
     vm.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

     vm.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];}



import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min';
import 'angular-chart.js/angular-chart;
angular
.module('app', [...,'chart.js',...])
```

I have no errors on the web browser console and no dependency injections errors but I have a blank space with nothing in it.
I'm fighting with this issue since yesterday...

If anyone was already faced with this problem, I don't say no to some helps.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Depending what version you upgraded FROM, there are some significant changes to the control objects processed by Chart.js.  Your code does not show the call to and data for creating the chart object.  That is the first place I would look.